# Can I store a formatted string like in printf?

Tags: c, string, string-formatting

Is there a way in C that I can format a string like I would in `printf`, but instead store it in a variable? I am trying to use this for system calls, so I can include a variable in the call.

Comment: [`sprintf()/snprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)?...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`sprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) (or [`snprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) in C99/C11) to format your string before using it.

```
int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);
int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);
```

Example:

```
 // Use the value of an integer 'n' as argument in 'perror' (C99).

#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char argument[sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT + 1];
snprintf(argument, sizeof argument, "%d", n);
perror(argument);
```

Comment: @ouah: Oh, I look tired. I wanted to write `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT`. Thanks.

Comment: For portable buffer sizes destined to contain a `%d` output, recommend `(1+sizeof(int)*3 +1)`.  `INT_MAX * CHAR_BIT` is a bit big.